# issue of virtual method in C#

Tags: c#, oop, virtual, abstract

In MSDN, it is mentioned,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4(VS.80).aspx

I am confused what does this item mean "A virtual inherited property can be overridden in a derived class by including a property declaration that uses the override modifier."?

(this is the 2nd differences between virtual and abstract)

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 10):

The only difference between virtual and abstract, is that an abstract method or propery has no implementation in the class where it has been defined (the abstract class), and that it **must** be overriden in a subclass; whereas a virtual method or property has an implementation in the class where it has been defined, and so it is not mandatory to override it in a subclass.

```
public abstract AbstractClass
{
    // This class cannot be instantiated, since it is 
    // abstract, and the class is abstract because
    // it has an abstract member

    public abstract MyProperty {get; set; }
}
```

In a class where you derive from AbstractClass (the above AbstractClass is just for explanation purposes; since it has no methods / properies that have an implementation, you could create an interface instead of an abstract class), you will have to provide an implementation of `MyProperty`.  Otherwise, it won't compile.
You do this by 'overriding' the MyProperty, you don't want to introduce a new member, but just provide an implementation for a property that has been defined previously.

```
public class ConcreteClass : AbstractClass
{
    public override MyProperty {
       get
       {
            return _someValue;
       }
       set
       {
            if( _someValue != value ) _someValue = value;
       }
}
```

Comment: So, you think MSDN means, for abstract base class, it is "must", but for non-abstract base class, it is "can" (not a must)?

Comment: It is defenitly a must; try to inherit from an abstract class, and don't override an abstract method or property; the compiler will complain.

Answer (score 6):

I can understand the confusion.  I have been there before, so I'll share how I keep the basic differences straight...

`virtual` vs. `abstract`:

- If a class method (or property) is
  marked `virtual`, then it **may be**
  overridden using the `override`
  keyword, if you choose to *inherit*
  (aka *derive*) from that class. 
  The `virtual` keyword is intended to evoke the idea that the method may or may not be the actual method called.  Therefore, I always think of `virtual` members as *default implementations*, meaning that it represents functionality that can be generalized, such as an `Eat()` method on a `Human` class, which might involve eating with one's hands. However, a `ChineseHuman` class might override the *default implementation* of `Eat()`, in order to allow for an implementation that uses chop sticks instead.  Finally, because virtual methods and properties are *default implementations*, the class that defines that member must provide a complete implementation of the method or property.  All `Human` objects must *know how to* `Eat()`.  
  An object-oriented way of thinking might declare that `virtual` members represent *instincts*. To `Eat()` is an *instinct* of a `Human` class object.  A `ChineseHuman` may *learn* to `Eat()` with chop sticks.
- If a class method (or property) is
  marked `abstract`, then it **must
  be** overridden using the `override`
  keyword, if you choose to *inherit*
  from that class.
  The `abstract` keyword is intended to evoke the idea that the class only *supports* the capability represented by the member, and that there is not any common logic that can be generalized for that feature. In other words, `abstract` members are only *conceptual*, and therefore they lack an implementation.  It is a little confusing that C# asks us to `override` abstract members when we implement an inheritance relationship, but in this case it really means that we are overriding the empty concept with a concrete implementation.  An example of an `abstract` member of a `Human` class might be `Speak()`.  There would not be a common way of speaking for all `Human` objects, nor is it instinctual, because it requires language to express.  Note: Some might argue that `Speak()` belongs on an `interface` instead.
  An object-oriented way of thinking might declare that `abstract` members represent behavior (methods) *to be learned* and knowledge or beliefs (properties) *to be acquired*.  To `Speak()` is a *learned* behavior of a `Human` class object.  A `ChineseHuman` may learn to `Speak()` differently than an `EnglishHuman` and neither knows how to `Speak()` just because they are both `Human`.

Nuances:

- `virtual` methods do NOT need to be overridden.
- There is no such thing as a `virtual` class.
- `abstract` members can only appear on `abstract` classes.  In the above examples, having an `abstract` method on the `Human` class implies that `Human` is an `abstract` class, and that, therefore, a `Human` cannot be instantiated using the phrase `var baby = new Human();`.  Instead, the `BabyHuman` class should inherit from `Human`, and it should be instantiated as `var baby = new BabyHuman();`.  Because a `BabyHuman()` is a `Human` and `EnglishHuman` and `ChineseHuman` both also inherit from `Human`, `EnglishHuman` could inherit from `BabyHuman` instead of `Human`.  Being `Human` is `abstract` because we are all something more than simply `Human`.
- `abstract` members cannot be hidden, only their `override` implementations may be (further up the inheritance chain).  For example, `BabyHuman` must implement the `abstract` `Speak()` method as an `override`.  If `EnglishHuman` inherits from `BabyHuman`, it may then hide the `BabyHuman` implementation of `Speak()` with its own implementation by using the `new` keyword (see "Method Hiding in C#" reference below).
- `abstract` classes can have `virtual` members.  That's a main distinction between an `interface` and an `abstract` class.  In that sense, an `abstract` class can define both a contract and a template of the class' behavior, whereas an `interface` only defines a contract.

Code Reference:

- Abstract Class versus Interface
  By Rahman Mahmoodi
  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/abstractsvsinterfaces.aspx
- Method Hiding in C#
  By Chetan Kudalkar
  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cs_methodhiding.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain what's confusing about it?  Properties can be overridden like any other method.

```
public class Base {
  public virtual int Prop1 { get { ... } set { ... } }
}

public class Derived : Base {
  public override int Prop1 { get { ... } set { ... } }
```

Comment: My confusion is not overridden property, but why it is a differences between abstract and virtual -- ""A virtual inherited property can be overridden in a derived class by including a property declaration that uses the override modifier."? Please see the context of MSDN I quoted.

Comment: Abstract members have no implementation, and so _must_ be overridden. Virtual members have an implementation, and _may_ be overridden. That's the difference.

Comment: Understand, MSDN words are so fuzzy. :-)

Comment: I don't think this is what the doc meant, or if it did, it's a very bad choice of words. Still, it's the best explanation. The writer was probably just past the Ballmer peak. Yay MSDN!

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a method virtual in your base class you can override it in your derived class.

Example

```
class MyBaseClass
{
   public virtual void MyOverridableMethod()
   {
          ...
   }

}

class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
   public override void MyOverridableMethod()
   {
         ...
   }
}
```

Notice the override modifier in MyDerivedClass.

Comment: My confusion is what is the differences between abstract and virtual in the quoted words -- " virtual inherited property can be overridden in a derived class by including a property declaration that uses the override modifier"?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let's say you have a base class, and that that base class is, itself, derived from another class.

```
public class Bar : Foo
{
   virtual public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

What the virtual keyword means is that in a class derived from Bar, you can override SomeProperty to change its behavior:

```
public class Baz : Bar
{
   private int thisInt;
   override public int SomeProperty 
   {
      get { return thisInt; }
      set 
      {
         if(value < 0)
         {
            throw new ArgumentException("Value must be greater than or equal to zero.");
         }
         thisInt = 0;
      }
   }
}
```

**Clarification:** When an object of type Baz is used, its version of SomeProperty is invoked, unless the type is cast to Bar. If you define Baz's SomeProperty as virtual, classes derived from Baz can also override it (in fact, that may be required--can't recall right off the top of my head).

**Further Clarification:** An abstract method has no implementation; when you add one to your class, you must also mark the class as abstract, and you cannot instantiate new instances of it, like this:

```
MyAbstractType m = new MyAbstractType();
```

Virtual members, on the other hand, can have an implementation (like SomeProperty, above), so you don't have to mark the class abstract, and you can instantiate them.

Comment: Thanks Mike, you answered well but not what I am asking. My question is answered by Tor Haugen, and you can refer there. It is my fault that I do not make myself understood.

Comment: It is not required to override virtual members.

Comment: @George: I clarified the answer to accomodate your question.
@Frederik: Note that I said that "you can override" a virtual member.

Comment: @Mike: I was referring to this sentence of yours:
In fact, that may be required--can't recall right off the top of my head

Comment: @Frederik: Of course, you're right. I think I was trying to say something else. Way too early in the morning at that time, and I have no idea why I was trying to write that before enough coffee. :) Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Would someone care to explain the downvote? If I'm wrong, please point out where, and enlighten me. I'd rather learn than be left in the dark. Seriously.